# Is there an Eslint rule or plugin for React to detect and warn against recursive component calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, components, eslint

Is there an Eslint plugin or rule for React that will warn against recursive components?

I accidentally called a component calling itself and crashed the browser. I have read that there is such a thing as recursive components but I believe they are rare enough that I would like to add a warning to my Eslint configuration. Anyone using something like this or know of such a rule or plugin for Eslint?

I searched Google but found nothing.